# Levenshtein Distance between each word in a given string

Tags: natural-language-processing, similarity

From [Calculate Levenshtein distance between two strings in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/calculate-levenshtein-distance-between-two-strings-in-python) it is possible to calculate distance and similarity between two given strings(sentences).

And from [Levenshtein Distance and Text Similarity in Python](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/) to return the matrix for each character and distance for two strings.

Are there any ways to calculate distance and similarity between each word in a string and print the matrix for each word in a string(sentences)?

```
a = "This is a dog."
b = "This is a cat."

from difflib import ndiff

def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    for x in range(size_x):
        matrix [x, 0] = x
    for y in range(size_y):
        matrix [0, y] = y

    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    print (matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])

levenshtein(a, b)
```

**Outputs**

```
>> 3
```

**Matrix**

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]
 [ 2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12.]
 [ 3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11.]
 [ 4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
 [ 5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [ 6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.]
 [ 7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
 [ 9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
 [10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [12. 11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  2.  2.  2.  3.  4.]
 [13. 12. 11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  3.  3.  3.  3.  4.]
 [14. 13. 12. 11. 10.  9.  8.  7.  6.  5.  4.  4.  4.  4.  3.]]
```

General Levenshtein distance for character level shown in below fig. 
[image]

> **Is it possible to calculate Levenshtein Distance for Word Level?**

**Required Matrix**

```
          This is a cat

This
is
a
dog
```

Comment: Do you mean other distance metrics, or other ways to code the levenshtein distance process? if former, there are methods such as word embeddings like word2vec that work like a charm, if the latter, why not use existing libraries? `NLTK` library has Levenshtein function. take a look http://www.nltk.org/howto/metrics.html . Please elaborate if you are looking for a more precise answer

Comment: @Alireza Elaborated the Question. Please do have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import product

@lru_cache(maxsize=4095)
def ld(s, t):
    """
    Levenshtein distance memoized implementation from Rosetta code:
    https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python
    """
    if not s: return len(t)
    if not t: return len(s)
    if s[0] == t[0]: return ld(s[1:], t[1:])
    l1 = ld(s, t[1:])      # Deletion.
    l2 = ld(s[1:], t)      # Insertion.
    l3 = ld(s[1:], t[1:])  # Substitution.
    return 1 + min(l1, l2, l3)


a = "this is a sentence".split()
b = "yet another cat thing".split()

# To get the triplets.
for i, j in product(a, b):
    print((i, j, ld(i, j)))
```

To get a matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numpy as np

a = "this is a sentence".split()
b = "yet another cat thing , yes".split()

tripets = np.array([(i, j, ld(w1, w2)) for (i, w1) , (j, w2) in product(enumerate(a), enumerate(b))])
row, col, data = [np.squeeze(splt) for splt in np.hsplit(tripets, tripets.shape[-1])]
coo_matrix((data, (row, col))).toarray()
```

[out]:

```
array([[4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 3],
       [3, 7, 3, 4, 2, 2],
       [3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 3],
       [6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7]])
```

Answer (score 0):

well... simply put a `.split()` at the end of your first two lines:

```
a = "This is a dog.".split()
b = "This is a cat.".split()
```

Your algorithm works with the iterables, and the string is broken into it's characters. You do the split, and `a,b` would be a list of words, then your algorithm works on the word-level

Output on your example:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [1. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 1. 0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 2. 1. 0. 1.]
 [4. 3. 2. 1. 1.]]

1.0
```